# How do I link the content of a cell to another worksheet as opposed to the value?

Tags: excel

I realize my title doesn't really explain what I'm asking as I don't know the correct terminology but bear with me and I'll explain my question.

I know how to link two cells so that if one changes, the other does as well (i.e. cell C3 is linked to cell E5 by selecting cell C3 and entering "=E5"). But how do I link the information in the cell to another cell?

If my worksheet looks like this:
cell B1 - Grapes, cell C1 - 50
cell B2 - Apples, cell C2 - 60
and I link cell F1 to cell C2 with "=C2". If I change the order of cell B1 and cell B2 to become alphabetical then cell F1 is no longer linked to the value in cell C2 (50) but changes to the value that now becomes cell C2 (60). How do I link cell F1 to the actual value (50) in cell C2 even if the order changes.

Help... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an efficient method; if i correctly understood your question then you can use = to link two cells For example:
Sheet one can look like this

```
      A  B  C  D  E
  1   1  2  3  4  5
  2   5  4  3  2  1
  3   1  2  3  4  5
Total 7  8  9  10 11
```

Sheet two requires cell links so you do:

```
TotalForA  =Sheet1!A4    //output will be 7  
TotalForB  =Sheet1!B4    //output will be 8
.
.
.
```

In a simple word you can use = sign and click on whatever cell you're like to get.